# HierarchyRequestError 4 on IE and Edge on DOM manipulation

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer, web-component, dom-manipulation, stenciljs

I am developing a web component using stencilJS. I am using a slot for rendering the HTML, but I need to modify the HTML before it gets rendered, for that, I am using querySelector and appendChild function to manipulate DOM. This is working fine on Chrome but throws Hierarchy Error on IE and Edge. Here is my code:

render function in TSX:

```
    render () {
      return (
       <div class={`column-${this.column}`}>
         <slot/>
       </div>
     )
   }
```

Code to manipulate DOM:

```
componentDidLoad () {
    const container = this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector(`.column-${this.column}`) ?
      this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector(`.column-${this.column}`) : this.element.querySelector(`.column-${this.column}`)
    Array.from(this.element.children).forEach(node => {
      const elem = document.createElement('div')
      elem.appendChild(node)
      container.appendChild(elem)
    })
  }
```

The above code works perfectly on chrome but throws an error in IE on the line

```
container.appendChild(elem)
```

Comment: [`ShadowRoot` -> Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Andreas, I agree to the point that ShadowDOM is not supported by IE and Edge, but the error is not because of ShadowRoot. I have console logged the container and it is getting that on IE. The error is thrown when I try to call appendChild()

Comment: You are trying to use the shadowRoot.querySelector for assigning the value to the container. Can you try to use the simple JS code to make a test in IE that do the same thing to check whether it work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got hold of this one.

The error was occurring because of the incorrect hierarchy that was generated during run-time.

I solved the problem just by moving `<slot/>` outside of the `<div>`

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark your own solution as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.